# Efficiently loop over two matrices in R using sapply

Tags: r, loops, sapply

I'm trying to create a matrix that takes in indices from two separate matrices (both 200 x 1000, but could also have different column size) and computes a value based the function `ks.test` (Kologomorov-Smirnov test). Currently I have nested sapply functions that do create `KS.mat`, but this just makes the code cleaner, not faster. Is there a way to speed this up?

```
N1=100
N2=100
m=1000

set.seed(12345)
X1=matrix(rnorm(N1*m),nrow=N1)
X2=matrix(rnorm(N2*m),nrow=N2)

#Data matrix
dat = rbind(X1,X2)

#Create a matrix of permuted labels where X1 are labeled 1 and X2 are labeled 2
B=1000
label.mat=matrix(rep(rep(c(1,2),times=c(N1,N2)),B),ncol=B)
perm.mat=apply(label.mat,2,sample)

#Create matrix of KS statistics based on permuted labels and dat
KS.mat=sapply(seq(m),function(j) 
  sapply(seq(B),function(b) ks.test(dat[perm.mat[,b]==1,j],dat[perm.mat[,b]==2,j])$statistic))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a mathematical way to decrease the complexity of this task, but I have good news for you! Now that you rewrote your `for` loops with `sapply`, your are one step away from parallelizing it with `parSapply`. It should be as simple as this:

```
require('parallel')
cl = makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterExport(cl, c("perm.mat","B","dat"))
KS.mat=parSapply(cl, seq(m),function(j) 
  sapply(seq(B),function(b) ks.test(dat[perm.mat[,b]==1,j],dat[perm.mat[,b]==2,j])$statistic))
```

Expect a speed increase linked to the number of cores available on your machine.

Comment: Great! Thanks, I'll try it out and report back.